# Elastic search: Can't determine the version of elastic search:

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am trying to index about 80million documents to elastic search from HDFS using elastic search hadoop plugin on pyspark. If I try to insert the complete data in 1 shot,after indexing about 20 million documents, I start getting the above error and the spark job fails.
I tried setting a lot of different options like indexing a part of data, changing the number of retries parameter to unlimited, increasing the batch size. But nothing worked. Any help is appreciated.

Both HDFS and ES are on AWS. I am using ES version 5.2.

Comment: Did you loose the connection with ES after indexing 20M documents? Did you find anything in ES logs? How many nodes in ES cluster?

Comment: Nothing else in the logs. I have 3 dedicated master nodes and 5 data nodes. I have listed all the nodes in the es.nodes list while starting the pyspark job.